# bazel-run does not load all tensorflow packages that are loaded at bazel build

Tags: c++, tensorflow, bazel

I have a problem with run my c++ tensorflow app directly after reboot ubuntu.

normally I build app by bazel build

```
bazel build -c opt --local_resources 3072,4.0,1.0 --verbose_failures --config=monolithic //tensorflow/app/...
```

after build, when I execute

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/app/run
```

everything is work perfectly but, when I reboot ubuntu and execute firstly bazel-bin I have spam of this errors.

```
May 11 12:29:05 tegra-ubuntu start.sh[800]: 2018-05-11 12:29:04.622723: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:967] failed to alloc 2304 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN
May 11 12:29:05 tegra-ubuntu start.sh[800]: 2018-05-11 12:29:04.622849: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:967] failed to alloc 2304 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN
```

I guess that is a problem in loaded packages. When bazel build is executing before bazel-run, loading packages is correct.
There is a way to only load missing packages without earlier building? I need to run app immediately after start but my building process is to long to building before run app

---

**Solution:**

```
SessionOptions opts;
opts.config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_allow_growth(true);
session->reset(tensorflow::NewSession(opts));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does enabling `gpu_options.allow_growth` fix the problem?

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1029742/tensorflow-1-6-not-working-with-jetpack-3-2/

Comment: Thank you. set_allow_growth(true) resolve this problem.